# Scrollbar flicker in AJAX-based site

Tags: jquery, ajax, scrollbar

Almost my whole site is on AJAX. I'm using jQuery Address.

I noticed a problem where when I go from page to page and the scrollbar is shown then hidden my whole page flickers / jumps and it's making my site look bad.

Is it okay if I do this?

```
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 101%;
}
```

I found this solution googling, but some dude said it's bad He didnt mention why it's bad, though.

What do you guys do when you encounter this problem? Are there any other solutions? If you can tell me the pros and cons of each solution that will be awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this instead:

```css
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I suppose it's more explicit about your intentions.

Comment: can u please tell me what the pros and cons of each solution, i don't have experience with "hacking"

Comment: @Pinokyo: I suppose the solution given in your question could mess up height calculations on the `body`.